# What is the regex for these cases?

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

What is the regex for these cases:

**29000.12345678900**, expected result **29000.123456789**

**29000.000**, expected result **29000**

**29000.00003400**, expected result **29000.000034**

In short, I want to eliminate the 0 point if there is no 1-9 found again behind decimal and I also want to eliminate the dot (.) if actually the number can be considered as integer.

I use this regex

```
(?:.0*$|0*$)
```

but it gives me this result:

**29123.6** from **29123.6400**, 4 is gone from there.

When I tested the regex separately, it works perfectly,

`.0*$` gives me **29123** from **29123.0000**

`0*$` gives me **29123.6423** from **29123.642300**

Am I missing something with the combined regex?

Comment: Escape the dot, it is a special character.

Comment: Why not use `.rstrip('0')` or something similar?

Comment: it is necessary to add **language tag** for `regex` based questions..

Comment: I use Objective-C as my language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think regex is the best way of doing it, you can just use something like this:

```
\.?0+$
```

It works for both cases:

```
> '12300000.000001130000000'.replace(/\.?0+$/g, '')
"12300000.00000113"
> '12300000.000000000000'.replace(/\.?0+$/g, '')
"12300000"
```

Comment: @Asad: To me, it looked like the only inputs are floats.

Comment: Yes, the cases are only for float number and I still face the same case with my regex for your regex "29123.6 from 29123.6400, 4 is gone from there." :(

Comment: btw, I just checked, it also truncates the 00 for integer..for example, from 100 to 1 :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex

```
^\d+(\.\d*[1-9])?
-   -------------
|        |->this would match only if the digits after . end with [1-9] 
|
|->^ depicts the start of the string..it is necessary to match the pattern
```

that solves your problem

try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: I modified my regex to become: (?:.0*$|^\d+(\.\d*[1-9])?) but still the "29123.6 from 29123.6400, 4 is gone from there.":(

Comment: @Rendy you are using the wrong regex..the regex is `^\d+(\.\d*[1-9])?` and it is working

Comment: @Rendy no need of `(?:.0*$` use my above regex..u dont need to modify it..just `match` it with the above regex...

Comment: Oops sorry, but it doesn't work in Obj-C, I just wonder whether this is the ios bug. It doesn't eliminate the 0 significant number for all cases.

Comment: @Rendy paste the code you are in your question..that would help us to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

You simply want this:

```
^\d*(\.?\d*[1-9])?
```

1. `^\d*` that means one or more digit before the first group.
2. In the `()` that describes matching group.
3. `\.?` means single DOT`(.)` can be there but optional. `eg. (.)`
4. `\d*` there can be one or more digits. `eg. (1234)`
5. `\.?\d*` there can be one DOT and one or more digit `eg. (.123)`
6. `[1-9]` this includes only digit from 1 to 9 only excluding `0`. `eg. (2344)`

### [Regex](http://regexr.com?33akv)

Comment: same case with @Blender :(

Comment: still the same :( this is really strange

Comment: From `29123.6400` it comes `29123.64` so `4` is there..look at the regex demo I provided..@Rendy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Objective-C supports something like the following construct, but in Python you can do it completely without regular expressions using [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip):

```
In [1]: def shorten_number(number):
   ...:     return number.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')

In [2]: shorten_number('29000.12345678900')
Out[2]: '29000.123456789'

In [3]: shorten_number('29000.000')
Out[3]: '29000'
```